# Implementing if-then-else logic for number of points or area greater than x

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

I wish to alter this script (see below) that I use in model builder to choose which analysis to run next. I want to make "is state plane" process to run if "number of points (shapefile) is equal to or grater than 1". I also wish to have a second edition of the script that run the "is state plane" process if the area of a polygon (shapefile) has an area which is greater to or equal to 500m2 for example, how would I go about doing that?

```
  # Import modules
import arcpy
import sys
import traceback

# Set local variables
prj = "" 
indata = "C:/ToolData/well.shp" 
dsc = arcpy.Describe(indata) 
sr = dsc.spatialReference 
prj = sr.name.lower()

try:

   # check if indata is in StatePlane, has no PRJ, or one other than StatePlane
   if prj.find("_stateplane_") > -1:
       # Set the Is Unknown parameter to FALSE, and the Is StatePlane parameter to TRUE
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1,"false") #The first parameter refers to the "Is Unknown" variable
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2,"true") #The second parameter refers to the "Is StatePlane" variable
       arcpy.AddMessage("Coordinate system is StatePlane") 

   elif prj == "unknown": 
       # Set the Is Unknown parameter to TRUE, and the Is StatePlane parameter to FALSE
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1,"true") 
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2,"false") 
       arcpy.AddMessage("To continue, first define a coordinate system!") 

   else:
       # Set the Is Unknown parameter to FALSE, and the Is StatePlane parameter to FALSE
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1,"false") 
       arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2,"false") 
       arcpy.AddMessage("Coordinate system is not StatePlane or Unknown") 

except Exception as e:
    AddPrintMessage(e[0], 2)
```

Comment: You've got more problems than that, this is a 9.2 script! What do you mean by =/>? are you trying to say *greater than or equal to*? Are you assuming the data is projected into a metre based coordinate system? What do you mean by points? A feature class can contain points but points don't have an area, a polygon feature class has an area but can't contain points.

Comment: You have a tag for ModelBuilder but make no mention of using that in your question body.  Are you perhaps trying to implement [Using if-then-else logic in ModelBuilder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/using-if-then-else-logic-for-branching.htm#GUID-7D9A6084-DF7C-4DBF-9F8D-81E29A64D672)?

Comment: Use GetCount to count number of Points, and summary statistics or cursors to check total polygon area